# Forming a polyhedron from concave polygonal faces.

Tags: polyhedra

A polyhedron is a convex, three dimensional region bounded by a finite number of polygonal faces.

So is it possible that some of those polygonal faces be concave ? Can concave polygons be used in the process to form a 3D convex region ?

Comment: Excellent question! Mind posting some of your ideas first?

Comment: Since when did a polyhedron have to be convex? Most of the uniform polyhedra aren't: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron.

Answer (score 2):

No. Every intersection of two convex shapes (such as a convex polyhedron and the plane through one of its faces) is convex.

Comment: I can see how that is true intuitively but is there a name for this theorem? I'd be interested in looking up the proof.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow two faces to be coplanar (which would be an unusual admission!), then
you could build a cube of six copies each of the triangle and nonconvex pentagon
shown left below.

[image: Nonconvex]
But if no two faces are coplanar, then in the neighborhood of a nonconvex point
on the boundary of a nonconvex face, there must be two points determining a segment
(dashed right above) with the segment exterior to the polyhedron. And this means
the polyhedron fails the definition of convexity, and so is itself nonconvex.